# I want to add the dropdown value to mysql and save it

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I just want to add my dropdown values in mysql

i tried a lot of things but every time my localhost shows validation error or not adding my data

My view

```
<label for="rank_restriction">Rank Restriction</label>

<select  class="chosen-select" multiple="" id="ristrict" name="ristrict">
<?php foreach ($poll['rankname'] as $rank) {?>
<option value=""><?= $rank ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

And i am not sure what to do in controller please guide me

Comment: please post controller , model code also.

Comment: use print_r($rank); what it returns????

Answer (score 1):

1) If you are using select tag with `multiple` attribute, Use tag name as `name="ristrict[]"`.

2) And you can get selected options with `$_POST['ristrict']`

3) `$_POST['ristrict']` is array that contains selected options.

Here is the below complete code

```
<label for="rank_restriction">Rank Restriction</label>
<select  class="chosen-select" multiple="multiple" id="ristrict" name="ristrict[]">
    <?php foreach ($poll['rankname'] as $rank) 
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rank; ?>"><?php echo $rank; ?></option>
    <?php 
    } ?>
</select>
```

4) You can get selected options like this

```
$ristricts = $_POST['ristrict'];
foreach($ristricts as $ristrict)
{
    //Your logic here....
}
```